# Facebook opengraph story is not coming on all of my friends timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

I have created an opengraph story in my app and i am able to share the story using javascript sdk but, the story only publishes on the friends that are either as administrator or developer on the app. 
I guess my story is not publicly shown to all friend. do you have any idea guys what could it be ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two reasons why this might be happening:

1. You have sandbox mode on in your application settings.
2. Your story action is not yet approved by facebook.

My guess is its the latter. In this case when you have finished the feature for story generation in your web app, submit your action for approval. You can read about it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process/).

Hope this helps.